# Does facebook API allow searches on profile, networks, employer, school info in the account?

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, restfb

Does [facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) API allow searches on profile, networks, employer, school info in the account?

Comment: Poorly asked question, since when answered by two people, then amala wants a way to get public information without requiring the subjects to be search to be searched without a valid access token.  I'm -1ing this question due to it's incomplete nature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can develop an app which can request **user_education_history** and **user_work_history** from the users and your users give permissions then you have the information you are looking for. Otherwise you can't get those info directly.

Usually when a user allows you to access their basic information in an auth dialog (of your app), you have access to their **user id**, **name**, **profile picture**, **gender**, **age range**, **locale**, **networks**, **list of friends**, and **any other information they have made public**.

> To get access to any additional information about the user or their
>   friends you need to ask for specific permissions from the user.

You need to know more about [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) and how to ask for more permissions through [Auth Dialogue](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/) and then decide yourself that whether facebook api allows it (to access user's education history, work history etc) or not.

Comment: We are not worried about the profile permissions set by users, but for those which are open to public we would like the capability to search for such users in a dynamic fashion, my understanding is that its not possible. kindly clarify

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to access those information without user's permission and we can't search by what we can't access. So yes, we can't search users by their employer or educational institute directly using the facebook api.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#searching) part of the documentation details searching.

It states that:

> You can search over all public objects in the social graph

as work and education details require extra permission to read, they aren't public objects and so can't be searched on.